# How to join intersected polygons in raphael.js?

Tags: svg, raphael, intersection

Any help is appreciated.

The main problem that I have transparent fills for each polygon and they are shouldn't overlap.

[image]

W3 rules for setting multiple polygons in one path (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillRuleProperty)

Maybe, someone can explain how to use nonzero rule on practice for getting single polygon without holes.

```
Playground:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/extempl/wkyyhkht/

Comment: Regrettable that unnecessarily disadvantages. If you know the answer - share. Something is unclear - ask. What's the problem?

Comment: I would personally show an example of what you have on a jsfiddle, highlighting the problem and the code you have.

Comment: Well, I thought that problem is quite obvious.

Comment: I'm sure its obvious to you :). Wondering if this helps... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386642/if-two-partially-opaque-shapes-overlap-can-i-show-only-one-shape-where-they-ove

Comment: @Ian, well, this is kinda cool solution, and seems like I'll use it. But it makes difficult to work with objects like they were single object and there are appears some artifacts on more complex polygons. Also, it uses global opacity instead of alpha channel of fill color. Can you post it as answer, please?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what to do here :), I'm guessing if thats the answer it should be marked as a duplicate or something (as that answer may get updated) ? Its not my answer though, so happy for you to link it in the original question or something and mark as a dupe ?

Comment: @Ian I'm not sure either. All that I can do - post my own answer, but in this case, this answer less mine than yours ;)

Comment: Also, wondering if http://www.benknowscode.com/2013/09/using-svg-filters-to-create-shape-outlines.html helps, similar approach, still has the same issue though I guess.

Comment: @Ian, yes, thanks, it's cool for visualizing select or whatever, but, if you'll need change position of every point of polygon - you'll need that this thing act like a single polygon, in which case you'll definitely need join different polygons as single one.
So, those mostly hacks, but not needed solution. Btw, I'll be using them while they solve my problems.

Comment: You could put them in a set and move it ?

Comment: @Ian, yes, you can move entire shape, but you can't nicely change position of certain corner dot of the shape